# Can anyone explain me this java program? I am new to java

Tags: java

Could someone explain me this example program in details because I don't understand how it output 58?

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [ ] myArr = {6, 42, 3, 7};
        int sum=0;
        for(int x=0; x<myArr.length; x++) {
            sum += myArr[x];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You are looping over the values of the array...
the content is 6,42,3,7 and you are using a variable sum as acummulator.

you are just adding all the int elements in the array..

so **6+42+3+7 = 58**

Answer (score 0):

expand the loop:

```
int x;
int sum;
sum = sum + myArr[x=0];
sum = sum + myArr[x=1];
sum = sum + myArr[x=2];
sum = sum + myArr[x=3];
sum = sum + myArr[x=4];
```